# Show that $X\times Y$ has cardinality $c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This is problem 5 from section 1.4. of the book Real Analysis and Probability by R.M. Dudley:

Let $X$ be a nonempty set of cardinality less than $c$ ( $c$ is defined as the cardinality of $2^\mathbb{N}$), and let $Y$ have cardinality $c$. Show that $X\times Y$ has cardinality $c$. *Hint*: Reduce to the case where $X$ has cardinality $c$.

I proved the reduced case by showing that $2^\mathbb{N}\times 2^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $2^\mathbb{N}$, by considering the sequence $(z_n)$ formed by alternating the terms of two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$. But I can't figure out how to reduce the original problem to this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: When $X$ is nonempty it has at least one element. So if you can show that $\{\ast\}\times Y$ has cardinality $c$ and $X\times Y$ has cardinality $c$ (where $X$ has cardinality $c$), then of course every set with a "smaller" cardinality then $2^\mathbb{N}$ also has cardinality $c$.

Comment: @Cornman If $X$ has cardinality less than $c$ then $X\times Y$ has cardinality less than $2^\mathbb{N}\times Y$ which is $c$ (reduced case). On the other hand $c$ has the same cardinality as $\{\ast\}\times Y$ (since $Y$ has cardinality $c$) and since $\{\ast\}\times Y$ has cardinality less than $X\times Y$ we get $2^\mathbb{N}$  has cardinality less than $X\times Y$. So by Schroeder-Bernstein we get $X\times Y$ has cardinality $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alphie says himself in the comments, it’s simply a case of Schroeder-Bernstein (picking any $x_0 \in X$):

$$\mathfrak{c} = |Y| =  |\{x_0\} \times Y| \le |X \times Y| = |X| \times |Y| \le \mathfrak{c} \times \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}$$

(That last step is really the “crucial” fact here: we have an AC-free proof of that equality while without choice we would not know $\kappa\times \kappa = \kappa$ for an arbitrary cardinal number, but this proof does not use AC).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe the proof that $2^\mathbb{N}\times 2^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $2^\mathbb{N}$ did not use AC. So I guess AC is needed when we define $c$ to be the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Alphie no, I think that’s free of AC too. Why do you ask?

Comment: Sorry I thought you said we need AC to prove $\mathfrak{c} \times \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}$, but I understand we only need it to prove the stronger statement $\kappa\times \kappa = \kappa$ for all cardinals $\kappa$?

Comment: @Alphie the stronger one only. The other has an explicit bijection.